# How to handle concurrent docker login

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline code, I am using docker compose to create all local images and later tagging it and pushing it to docker repo.
Issue is I am not able to run multiple builds at same time, as I am doing docker login for pushing and later doing docker logout.

How can I handle concurrent docker login .

Answer (score 0):

You can use isolation in the form of Docker containers in a Jenkins Pipeline: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Each run will spin up a separate container with Docker compose and ensures the current working directory is mounted inside that container. Any docker logins / logouts will only happen inside that container, so everything is nicely isolated, allowing multiple concurrent runs.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'docker/compose:1.26.2'
            registryUrl '[YOUR REGISTRY URL]'
            registryCredentialsId '[YOUR_USERNAME+PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS_ID]'
            args '-u 1000:[GROUP_ID_OF_THE_DOCKER_GROUP] -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --entrypoint=""'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Package') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker version'
                sh 'docker-compose version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we tell Jenkins to do the work inside a Docker container containing Docker compose. This container can be authenticated to a private Docker registry, by specifying the `registryUrl` and `registryCredentialsId` (from the Jenkins credential store). The argument `args` we pass to the container makes sure that 1) the Docker socket is volume mounted into the container (to prevent unix:////var/run/docker.sock not found, is Docker running? errors) and 2) we run as a user in the Docker group (prevents Permission denied errors). This group id of the docker group can be found by executing `cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group sudo)` on the Jenkins agent that runs this Pipeline.

Within the `stage` you now have both Docker and Docker compose available, which can access your private registry.

Comment: Can we implement this without using new docker container